# Pointer to a Pointer in C?

Tags: c, pointers

Chart I have to use to find the value of `a`, `p`, `pp`, `*p`, `*pp`, and `**pp`:

```
Variable    Address    Value

            36          4
 a          40          1
            44          2
            48         44
 p          52         40
            56         36
            60         44
pp          64         52
            68         56
```

I arrive at:

```
a = 1
p = 40
pp = 52

*p = 52
*pp = 64
```

Is `**pp` as simple as taking the value located at `*pp` (52)?? This is really my only idea, otherwise I am confused as to what to do.

Comment: `*p` and `*pp` don't make sense. They are de-referencing `p` and `pp`, but those are not pointers. Do you mean `&p` and `&pp`?

Comment: Spend more time reading books (or web pages) about *address space*, *virtual memory*, *process*, *C programming*, *pointer*. Compile your program with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) then use a debugger (`gdb`) to run your program step by step and display some data (e.g. pointer variable, and dereference them)

Comment: `*` works in the exactly opposite way from what you have guessed.

Answer (score 4):

You have `&` (address of) and `*` (dereference) confused.

- `&` operator gives you the address of the operand
- `*` operator gives you the value at the address pointed to by the operand

Answer (score 1):

Given your chart and variables,

```
*pp = *(52) = *(&p) = p = 40
```

Looked at another way,

```
 pp = &p
```

And

```
*p = *(40) = *(&a) = a = 1
```

which means

```
p = &a
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how everything works out:

```
 &pp             = 64
  pp = &p        = 52
 *pp =  p  = &a  = 40
**pp = *p  =  a  =  1
```